# Cancelling and re-executing ReactiveCommand

Tags: c#, reactiveui

I'm struggling with a ReactiveUI use case that I feel is so simple there must be "out-of-the-box" support for it. But I cannot find it.

The scenario is a basic search interface with these features:

- A search string TextBox where the user enters the search text
- A result TextBox where the result is presented
- An indicator showing that a search is in progress

The search should work like this:

- The search string TextBox is throttled, so that after 500ms of
  inactivity, a search operation is initiated.
- Each time a new search is initiated any ongoing search operation should be cancelled.

Basically I'm trying to extend the "Compelling example" to cancel the currently executing command before starting a new command.

Seems easy enough? Yeah, but I cannot get it right using ReactiveCommand. This is what I have:

```
var searchTrigger = this.WhenAnyValue(vm => vm.SearchString)
    .Throttle(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500))
    .Publish().RefCount();
var searchCmd = ReactiveCommand.CreateFromObservable(
    () => Observable
        .StartAsync(ct => CancellableSearch(SearchString, ct))
        .TakeUntil(searchTrigger));
searchCmd.ToPropertyEx(this, vm => vm.Result);
searchCmd.IsExecuting.ToPropertyEx(this, vm => vm.IsSearching);
searchTrigger.Subscribe(_ => searchCmd.Execute(Unit.Default).Subscribe());
```

The above code works in all aspects except `searchCmd.IsExecuting`. I kick off a new search regardless of the state of `searchCmd.CanExecute`. This makes `IsExecuting` unreliable since it assumes serial operation of the commands. And I cannot use `InvokeCommand` instead of `Execute` since then new searches would not be started while a search is in progress.

I currently have a working solution without `ReactiveCommand`. But I have a strong feeling this simple use case should be supported in a straightforward way using `ReactiveCommand`. What am i missing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

AFAICT Rx7 doesn't really handle this kind of overlapping execution. All the messages will eventually make it through but not in a way that will keep your IsExecuting consistently true.  Rx6 used an In flight counter so overlapping executions were handled but Rx7 simplified it all way down. Most likely for performance and reliability (but I'm just guessing).  Because Tasks aren't going to cancel right away that first command is going to complete after the second command starts which leads to IsExecuting toggling from true to false to true to false.  But that middle transition from false to true to false happens instantly as the messages catch up.  I know you said you had a non Reactive Command working but here's a version that I think works with Reactive Commands by waiting for the first command to finish or finish cancelling. One advantage to waiting until the Task actually cancels is that you are assured you don't have two hands in the cookie jar :-) Which might not matter in your case but can be nice in some cases.

```
//Fires an event right away so search is cancelled faster
var searchEntered = this.WhenAnyValue(vm => vm.SearchString)
    .Where(x => !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x))
    .Publish()
    .RefCount();



ReactiveCommand<string, string> searchCmd = ReactiveCommand.CreateFromObservable<string, string>(
    (searchString) => Observable.StartAsync(ct => CancellableSearch(SearchString, ct))
                    .TakeUntil(searchEntered));

//if triggered wait for IsExecuting to transition back to false before firing command again
var searchTrigger = 
    searchEntered
        .Throttle(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500))
        .Select(searchString => searchCmd.IsExecuting.Where(e => !e).Take(1).Select(_ => searchString))
        .Publish()
        .RefCount();

_IsSearching =
    searchCmd.IsExecuting
    .ToProperty(this, vm => vm.IsSearching);


searchTrigger
    .Switch()
    .InvokeCommand(searchCmd);
```

Comment: Great answer. Thanks. Serializing the operations is indeed an option. But since cancelling could take some time to complete, I'd prefer just "forgetting" about the ongoing operation and immediately start a new.